# Laravel Eloquent Accessor not working in relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Model **RelationDetails** with 1 accessor:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
   return "{$this->FirstName} {$this->Name}";
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
$annualPasses = Subscription::entrance()
    ->whereHas('Activation', function($query)
    {
        $query->whereDate('ValidUntil', '>=', Carbon::now());
    })
    ->with('RelationDetails')
    ->get();
```

But when I want to use in my blade: `$annualpass->RelationDetails->FullName` I got the error:
**Trying to get property 'FullName' of non-object**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the ouput when you dd($annualpass?)

Comment: `App\Subscription {#1986 ▼
  #connection: "sqlsrv"
  #table: "Subscription"
  #primaryKey: "SubscriptionId"
  +incrementing: false
  +timestamps: false
  #keyType: "int"
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:16 [▶]
  #original: array:16 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▶]
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}`

Comment: How are you returning the data to the view?

Comment: On this way: `return view('index')->with(['annualPasses' => $annualPasses]);`
In my blade I have a foreach: `@foreach($annualPasses as $annualPass)`

Comment: Is the connection between `Subscription` and `RelationDetails` a one-to-one relation?  And does every Subscription have a `RelationDetails`, from the error it looks to me like one of your subscriptions does not have a `RelationDetails`.

Comment: @Remul I guess you were right. I added `->whereHas('RelationDetails)` and the problem is solved. I gues one the records doesn't have RelationDetails..

Answer (score 1):

It's suppose to be `$annualpass->RelationDetails->full_name`

Also, `return "{$this->FirstName} {$this->Name}";` means that in your DB, your column name is **FirstName** ... I recommend **first_name** that way **{$this->first_name}**. Of course you will have to update your migrations as well.

I recommend going through [Laravel Best Practises](https://www.laravelbestpractices.com/). Please follow naming standards. Things get easier that way.

Comment: `$annualpass->RelationDetails->full_name` gives the same result: **Trying to get property 'full_name' of non-object**

I understand your point about the column names, but it is an existing (non-laravel application) where I'm getting the data from. Therefore, I have no influence on these column names.

Comment: While I do agree with you, this is not the problem, since the op is trying to call a property on a non object, so it does not even get to the accessor.